# is there an elegant way to inject a spring managed bean into a java custom/simple tag

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, jstl

I have a bunch of java custom tags that use spring managed beans.. since i cant find a way to inject into a custom tag, i created a helper class that provides static methods to "getTheObjectINeedBean()" for all the spring bean objects i need..  I do not like this approach at all.

i really want to be able to inject a spring managed bean into the custom tag

Is there a way?  As far as my research goes, I understand there is no way to do this, because the custom tag is container managed

Thanks,

Billy

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296052/how-to-inject-spring-beans-into-a-jsp-2-0-simpletag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct there isn't a simple way to use dependency-injection in jstl tags, because they are not managed by spring, and cannot be. However there are (at least) two workarounds:

- `@Configurable` - aspectJ allows you to plug a weaver at load-time/compile-time, so that even objects that are not instantiated by spring can be spring aware. See [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj)
- You can create a base tag class for your project, and call an `init(..)` method from every `doStartTag(..)` method. There, you can get the `ServletContext` from the `pageContext`, and thus obtain the spring `ApplicationContext` (via `ApplicationContextUtils`). Then:

  ```
  AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = appCtx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
  factory.autowireBean(this);
  ```

Neither options are perfect as they require either some additional code, or some "black magic"

Answer (score 8):

To expand on @Bozho's post, I have gotten this to work like so: (in spring 3.0 there is no ApplicationContextUtils that I could find)

```
public class LocationTag extends RequestContextAwareTag {
    @Autowired
    PathComponent path;

...
    @Override
    protected int doStartTagInternal() throws Exception {
        if (path == null) {
            log.debug("Autowiring the bean");
            WebApplicationContext wac = getRequestContext().getWebApplicationContext();
            AutowireCapableBeanFactory acbf = wac.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
            acbf.autowireBean(this);
        }
        return SKIP_BODY;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks "getRequestContext().getWebApplicationContext()" solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

The solution as described above works but some background and additional code snippets are, quite likely, useful.

1) The doStartTagInternal method is invoked from the doStartTag method. 
2) I was forced to set the pageContext first before invoking the doStartTag 
3) I did a lookup of the bean as opposed to the autowiring. To me this seems more straightforward: (YourBeanProxy) autowireCapableBeanFactory.getBean("yourBeanName")

Hopefully this additional info is useful.