# Inject Bean in Custom tag Java - @Configurable

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, taglib

I am having trouble injecting a service into a custom tag I created:

```
@Configurable
public MyTag extends BodyTagSupport{

 @Autowired
 private MyService service;

 @Override
 public int doStartTag(){
 ......
  service.callServiceMethod(); // service is null
 ....
 }
 .......
}
```

Is there a way to inject beans using @Configurable in Custom Tags? I do not want to use following approach to inject beans:

```
 ServletContext sc = ((PageContext) getJspContext()).getServletContext();
 ApplicationContext context = 
   WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(sc);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Configurable requires Compile time or load time weaving using AspectJ to be enabled. It will not work with normal Spring AOP, can you please confirm your project uses AspectJ.

Comment: No, It does not, unfortunately. However, if the project used AspectJ. The approach I used will work right? Or am I still missing something? Also, is there any annotation that I could use for Spring-driven bean injection here?

Comment: Yes, it will work if you have AspectJ enabled for your project. Outside of Aspectj the only approach is one recommended in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3445908/204788