# Why Spring's @Component does not work on a JSP Custom Tag class?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, jsp-tags

I have a custom tag:

```
@Component
public class CVTag extends SimpleTagSupport {

@Inject
private JaxbSupport jaxbSupport;

@Override
public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {
    JspWriter writer = getJspContext().getOut();
    Groups groups = jaxbSupport.getJaxbGroups();
}
```

`NullPointerException` is thrown as `jaxbSupport` is null.

Is there really a limitation stipulating Custom-Tag cannot be a Spring managed Bean? or I am doing something wrong?

Using Spring 3.2.4.
Thanks.

Comment: Tags aren't spring beans and as such cannot be injected. You will have to lookup the bean from the application-context.

Comment: @M.Deinum to clarify, I'm not injecting a Tag. I'm injecting a Spring Bean into the Tag.

Comment: Correct that is also what I'm stating. To do injection the Tag also has to be a spring managed bean. Spring can only inject into beans it knows, the Tag is under control of the JSP lifecycle and not spring.

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there an elegant way to inject a spring managed bean into a java custom/simple tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445908/is-there-an-elegant-way-to-inject-a-spring-managed-bean-into-a-java-custom-simpl)