# Eclipse hangs for 3-4 seconds before displaying a tooltip message

Tags: html, eclipse, editor, freeze, eclipse-wtp

I've searched the Internet like crazy, however "WTP freeze" or "Eclipse freeze" yields so many different results that it's virtually impossible to find the right one. I have the following issue.

In a HTML or CSS editor when I accidentally hover my mouse over an attribute value, Eclipse hangs for 3-4 seconds with CPU at 100% load before producing a tooltip message with some info on the tag and its attribute. I don't need those tips. Hell, I don't even need syntax coloring if that would prevent me from this hang.

I tried disabling all the autocomplete features, everything that seemed related, however that didn't change a bit. I looked for a setting to disable WTP completely without uninstalling it, however again - no luck.

I use Eclipse Helios. I have all the latest plugins. I'll supply any additional info, if that is needed.

Has anybody had a similar issue and was able to resolve it? This is really driving me crazy.

**BOUNTY**

The bounty will go to anyone who finds a way or a workaround that will **make pop-up windows reasonably fast**. I've had this issue in Eclipse in numerous places - like PyDev for example:

[Eclipse PyDev completion hangs (yet again)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463691/eclipse-pydev-completion-hangs-yet-again)

I have a strong programistic feeling that this is a general issue with pop ups and not so much with WTP/PyDev. Here are measures that I've already taken:

- Installed the latest Eclipse from scratch
- Installed the two problematic plugins on this clean installation (WTP/PyDev)
- Made sure that Eclipse has more than enough memory
- Made sure the appropriate JVM is chosen

My setup is Ubuntu Natty, Oracle Java 1.6 - latest version in the repos

**Further findings**

Ok, I've just found out that 99% of the time of the freeze is spent inside a call to `org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._gtk_widget_realize` which doesn't seem right. Any clues?

I'd encourage everyone who has experienced this issue to **[vote for this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=358037)** on the Eclipse bug tracker.

Comment: How about just not hovering over a tag? Tooltips are there for a purpose, but they're not designed to get in the way, hence the 3-4 second delay.

Comment: Oh, come on, you're not being serious, are you?

Comment: Sounds like I just killed a family member of yours. Sorry for tugging on a nerve. Evidently I misunderstood the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse webtools project (WTP) and its performance / quality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433991/eclipse-webtools-project-wtp-and-its-performance-quality)

Comment: @BalusC It's not a duplicate by any measure. This is a concrete issue, whereas the one you're linking to is a rather general question.

Comment: Ah, I faced a similar problem, but shied way for lack of confidence at finding a solution.  Thanks.

Comment: @SidCool Do you think it is exactly the same issue? And what is your desktop environment?

Comment: Yes, @julkiewicz, it was the issue when hovering over elements in JSP, Eclipse became unresponsive.  It was a cause of lot of frustration.  Thanks again.

Comment: @SidCool Would you perhaps mind writing a comment under my bug report (assuming of course it is the same issue)? I think we could push this thing through together. I really think someone should look into it.

Comment: I agree.  We can do it. I will update your bug report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, finally nailed it, thanks to one of the suggestions.

Hover messages can be disabled under Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Structured Text Editors > Hovers tab > Combined Hover.

Eclipse can be a labyrinth sometimes.

Comment: The downside of this is that you then have no tooltips. As unnecessary as they may be at times, they CAN be useful in some cases.

Comment: Yea, I agree - hence the whole bounty thing. The thing is, I thought they take so much time to calculate. But now it turns out that because of some nasty bug in the UI, they take so much time to merely display. Please, vote for a bug report if you experience a similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

You could try switching off all the Validators: Window > Preferences > Validation > Suspend all validators.

Another option is Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Hovers, turn off 'Combined Hover'.

Comment: No luck, but +1 for concrete suggestions.

Comment: Wow, finally nailed it, thanks to your suggestion. Hover messages can be disabled under Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Structured Text Editors > Hovers tab > Combined Hover.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where Eclipse would hang on tooltips for several seconds, and oftentimes crash. It got to the point where it would just plain crash even if I didn't do anyhting. Uninstalling it and reinstalling it got rid of the problem, though, so I suggest giving that a try if you haven't already.

Comment: I've deleted a workspace once or twice, and started from scratch. I don't know if that would be equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

How is your memory profile? Do you have more than enough?

We have run into many problems with Eclipse and wierd issues as we approached our memory limits. The current prevailing thought is that the swapping causes problems due to timing issues.

Comment: It looks too regular for a memory issue. Also I've got still about a quarter of my memory free.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse sometimes downloads the the javadoc as requested, the hang your seeing may be the lag time it takes for that particular part of the javadoc to download.

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer didn't work for me in Eclipse (Kepler) with PyDev.

For me the following worked best:

`Show Docstrings` should be disabled in preferences under `Pydev/Editor/Hover`.

Answer (score -1):

This looks to be a gtk specific issue. In addition to the bug you mentioned there are other bugs opened as well e.g. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=345093.

Comment: I've linked to this bug in my report. I also think this is a gtk specific issue or even Gnome3 specific issue. Not sure why the downvote...