# How to show values from property file in JSP in a spring MVC app

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm setting my properties in `app-servlet.xml` with a bean like this:

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/my.properties"></property>
    </bean>
```

Most of the time I access the properties in my controllers or other classes like this:

```
@Value("${dbtype}")
public String dbType;
```

But what if I want to use a property in a JSP file and bypass the controller. Meaning I don't want the value type being passed from the controller to the JSP as a model attribute.

Is there a way to access properties directly in a jsp?

Comment: check this link                                                       http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?96715-Reading-values-stored-in-properties-file-from-JSP

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Spring config**

```
<util:properties id="propertyConfigurer" 
                  location="classpath:yourPropertyFileClasspathHere "/>
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="propertyConfigurer" />
```

**jsp**

```
<spring:eval expression="@propertyConfigurer.getProperty('propertyNameHere')" />
```

Comment: And you have to add spring taglib to page:

<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

Comment: <spring:eval expression="@environment.getProperty('propertyNameHere')" /> worked for me using propertyConfigurer on newer versions of spring.

Answer (score 24):

What you can also do that doesn't tie you to looking up properties in a single property placeholder, or if you are using java config and just instantiating a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer is use the environment object:

```
<spring:eval expression="@environment.getProperty('application_builtBy')" />
```

Comment: I find this one more helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" 
    id="messageSource"
    p:basenames="WEB-INF/i18n/site"
    p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false"/>
```

Now this is your **Properties File**

```
site.name=Cool Bananas
```

And here goes your **JSP**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><spring:message code="site.name"/></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for specifying the tag library declaration.  This is omitted way too often.

Answer (score 1):

In context just do this:

```
<util:properties 
    id="propertyConfigurer"
    location="classpath:yourPropertyFileClasspathHere"
/>
<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="propertyConfigurer" />
```

for creating Properties bean(same as @nkjava.blogspot.com in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15111620/449553)).
But this is not all work need todo.

Now you need to expose this bean to JSP.
There are few way to do this, depends on type of view resolver. There is solution for [InternalResourceViewResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1296548/449553) -  you need to set "exposeContextBeansAsAttributes" to true and populate "exposedContextBeanNames" with list of required beans.

For [tiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848415/accessing-spring-beans-from-a-tiles-view-jsp) also are solution.

Than you can simply use this bean in your JSP. Via EL for example:

```
${propertyConfigurer['my.string.from.prop.file']}
```

Comment: After 11 years, this saved me. Thank you so much. I am using Tiles and without this method, I couldn't use the properties bean on my JSP.

Answer (score -2):

### in Spring version 4, you find the property file :

### 1) xml mode

```
                <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
                   <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
                      <property name="locations">
                          <list>
                            <!-- default resources folder (default package maven project) -->
                             <value>classpath:mongodb.remote.properties</value>  
                                <!-- Or in /WEB-INF/ folder -->
                              <value>/WEB-INF/mongodb.remote.properties</value>  
                          </list>
                      </property>
                  </bean>
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### 2) programmatic mode:

```
    If you have for example this package : com.profile.config, com.profile.controller, ecc.. 
    it's not problem if you put only com.profile, it's ok !!! Now


    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.profile")
    /** resources folder & default package maven project*/
    @PropertySource(value = { "classpath:mongodb.remote.properties" }) 
    public class MyPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer {


        @Bean
        public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
            return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        }
    }


    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Your property file

    label.test.val=this is the property file value!!!!!
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    @Controller
    public class LabelsAndValuesController {


         @Value("${label.test.val}")
         String test;

    }
```

### output:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    this is the property file value!!!!!
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```