# How to get properties in JSP files using spring mvc 3

Tags: spring

I am very new to spring mvc 3 annotation based application. I have two properties files - 
WEB-INF\resources\general.properties, 
WEB-INF\resources\jdbc_config.properties

Now I want to configure them through spring-servlet.xml. How I can achieve this?

In general.properties,

```
label.username = User Name:
label.password = Password:
label.address = Address:
```

...etc
jdbc_config.properties,

```
app.jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
app.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:[port_number]/
app.jdbc.username=root
app.jdbc.password=pass
```

---etc

If I want to get label.username and app.jdbc.driverClassName in my jsp page, how do I code for them?

I also want to access these properties values from my service. How to get these property values using respective keys in method level in service class or controller class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show values from property file in JSP in a spring MVC app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111260/how-to-show-values-from-property-file-in-jsp-in-a-spring-mvc-app)

Answer (score 17):

You need to distinguish between application properties (configuration) and localisation messages. Both use JAVA properties files, but they serve different purpose and are handled differently.

**Note:** I am using Java based Spring configuration in the examples bellow. The configuration can be easily made in XML as well. Just check Spring's [JavaDoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/) and [reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html).

---

**Application Properties**

Application properties should be loaded as *property sources* within your application context. This can be done via [`@PropertySource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) annotation on your `@Configuration` class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:default-config.properties")
public class MyConfig  {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

}
```

Then you can inject properties using [`@Value`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) annotation:

```
@Value("${my.config.property}")
private String myProperty;
```

---

**Localisation Messages**

Localisation messages is a little bit different story. Messages are loaded as [resource bundles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) and a special resolution process is in place for getting correct translation message for a specified [locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

In Spring, these messages are handled by [`MessageSource`s](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html). You can define your own for example via [`ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html):

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("/WEB-INF/messages/messages");
    return messageSource;
}
```

You can access these messages from beans if you let Spring inject `MessageSource`:

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;

public void myMethod() {
    messageSource.getMessage("my.translation.code", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
}
```

And you can translate messages in your JSPs by using `<spring:message>` tag:

```
<spring:message code="my.translation.code" />
```

Comment: thanks for notifying me diff. between application properties (configuration) and localisation messages ... please update how to access **value** from **application properties** in jsp,

Comment: **if your messages file is located outside .jar** :: assume you have file path/to/messages_en.properties on base name you have to set : messageSource.setBasename("file:path/to/messages") omitting the suffix _en.properties

Comment: easiest way is to use <spring:eval expression="@environment.getProperty('application_builtBy')" />

Answer (score 4):

I ended up using Environment

Add these lines to config

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/configs/env.properties")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{...}
```

You can get the properties from controller using autowired Environment

```
public class BaseController {
    protected final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    public Environment env;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String rootPage(ModelAndView modelAndView, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        LOG.debug(env.getProperty("download.path"));
        return "main";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Firstly import spring tag lib:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="security" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
```

Than import property from your application.properties

```
<spring:eval var="registration_url" expression="@environment.getProperty('service.registration.url')"/>
```

Than use your variable

```
<a href="<c:out value="${registration_url}"/>" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> test </a>
```