# Access the Spring Properties in jsp

Tags: spring, jsp, struts2

We are using strusts2+spring3.2+struts.spring.plugin
Also we are using the property place holder to access the properties in actions

Something like:

```
@Value("${web.site.name}") private String siteName;
```

And we have siteName ready and populated.

Is it possible that we can access the value in the JSP pages too? Or we should first get it from struts action and then pass it to JSP.

Comment: Are you using Spring Controllers to pass it back to the JSP page. I am asking because I haven't worked on Struts + Spring. If you are using Spring Controller, in the ModelAndView object you can add the siteName value and access it from JSP

Comment: Since you are using struts2 as your MVC framework, proper way to do is to pass all such values to UI using Controller (Actions class in struts2)

Comment: You can use localization tag to get values from properties files.

Comment: @DhanushGopinath I am using struts!

Comment: @AleksandrM good comment! But with spring, you can have properties from different locations, property files, xml files, java environment...

Comment: Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15111260/1700321.

Comment: The same way you could always use `getText()` to get your properties.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can't. But if you can, you shouldn't... You should pass the value using controller. One way to use the property directly in the jsp is to write custom tag that reads the property file and choose the one that you need.

Example(not tested):

```
public class TemplateTag extends SimpleTagSupport{

    private String propName;//add setter to get it from the tag attribute

    public void doTag()throws JspException, IOException{
        JspWriter out = getJspContext().getOut();
        Properties prop = new Properties();
                prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));


        out.print(prop.getProperty(propName));
    }
```

As Aleksandr M suggested you can use the built in tags: http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-internationalizing-or-localization-example/

Comment: There is no need for custom tag. Struts2 as well Spring provides such tags.