# In the Spring Framework for Java, what is the best way to store elements defined in the .properties file into a variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring

I currently have a Java Spring project where the bulk of the front is in AngularJS, HTML, etc. I currently have an application.properties file that holds:

```
    name:myName
    idNum:8888888888
    password:squirrels
    contextPath:/ilovesquirrels-ui
    server:0000

    ui.firstLink: www.google.com
    ui.secondLink: www.yahoo.com
    ui.thirdLink: www.w3schools.com

    myBool: False
```

The first five seem to read in automatically to a place I cannot seem to find. The last four, I'd like to access in Javascript to store the urls and the boolean. I'd like to write something in JS like:

```
    var myLink1 = "something that accesses ui.firstLink in application.properties";

    var myLink2 = "something that accesses ui.secondLink in application.properties";

    var myLink3 = "something that accesses ui.thirdLink in application.properties";
```

Right now, I am reading information from a Javascript file that holds a JSON object that I'd eventually like to get rid of. It was all the same information as application.properties, except it is more visible to the end user. How do I get the links from my application.properties file into Javascript variables?

Comment: Have a Spring MVC web Service expose the properties you wish to share and implement a web Service call from your JS Client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like to mix JavaScript with the server-side language as it:

- makes life harder for editors
- is harder to read
- couples JS with the server-side technology

**Therefore, I would put the desired variable expressions as meta tags or data-attributes and then access them using JS.**

- `<body data-uifirstlink='<%=properties.getProperty("uifirstLink")%>';`
  accessed with jQuery by: `$('body').data('uifirstlink');`

  **note:** ideally, these data attributes should be as contextual as possible (instead of `body` choose a more specific place).
- `<meta name='uifirstlink' content='<%=properties.getProperty("uifirstLink")%>' />`
  accessed with jQuery by: `$('meta[name="uifirstlink"]').prop('content')`

A service for retrieving properties is **not** good because:

- You need to wait for the page to load to run the call and use the variables
- You have unnecessary Ajax calls
- You create more coupling between client and server

Finally, you could consider cookies or headers, but I don't think is so straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a jsp file with this:

```
<script>
    var myLink1 = '<%=properties.getProperty("ui.firstLink")%>';
</script>
```

If you want to use spring, create a PopertiesPlaceHolderConfigurer and use spring tags in jsp. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111260/how-to-show-values-from-property-file-in-jsp-in-a-spring-mvc-app)