# Inject a spring service in jsp page

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

i'am working on an application with springmvc, i was wondering how can i inject a sping service in my jsp page.i've tried somethings but its doesn't seem to work

my service look like that :

```
            @Service
            @Transactional
            public class CompteMarcheService {

                @Autowired
                private Compte_ProjetRep service;


                public int test()
                {
                    return 10;
                }
```

and what i've added in my root-context

```
       <bean class="
         org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
           <property name="exposedContextBeanNames">
              <list>
                 <value>CompteMarcheService</value>
              </list>
           </property>
        </bean>
```

and finaly , the jsp page

```
      <c:set var="clients" scope="request" value="${CompteMarcheService.test()}"/>
```

but when i try to display the clients var like that : ${clients} i get empty field , any help please i need to know how to inject correctly my service

thanks.

Comment: thank you , but this is possible with spring and its used by a lot of people

Answer (score 0):

From [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-name-generator):

> 5.10.6 Naming autodetected components
>
> When a component is autodetected as part of the scanning process, its
>   bean name is generated by the BeanNameGenerator strategy known to that
>   scanner. By default, any Spring stereotype annotation ( @Component,
>   @Repository, @Service, and @Controller) that contains a name value
>   will thereby provide that name to the corresponding bean definition.
>
> If such an annotation contains no name value or for any other detected
>   component (such as those discovered by custom filters), the default
>   bean name generator returns the uncapitalized non-qualified class
>   name. For example, if the following two components were detected, the
>   names would be myMovieLister and movieFinderImpl:

```
@Service("myMovieLister") 
public class SimpleMovieLister { }

@Repository 
public class MovieFinderImpl implements MovieFinder { }
```

Try to use `compteMarcheService` instead of `CompteMarcheService`.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="exposedContextBeanNames">
    <list>
      <value>compteMarcheService</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>

<c:set var="clients" scope="request" value="${compteMarcheService.test()}"/>
```

Comment: thanks , but i still have the same problem , i get an empty field .

Answer (score 0):

If you would like toe xpose classes (beans) to JSP's you could do it as either a Tag library or there is also one more way

```
<bean    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
   <property name="exposeContextBeansAsAttributes" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myBean" class="com.x.MyClass"/>
```

Here is a post

[How to inject spring beans into a jsp 2.0 SimpleTag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296052/how-to-inject-spring-beans-into-a-jsp-2-0-simpletag)

Answer (score 0):

Just have done the same thing using annotations:

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver tilesViewResolver() {
  final UrlBasedViewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
  ...
  viewResolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
  viewResolver.setExposedContextBeanNames("myBean");
  return viewResolver;
}
```

And in my .jsp:

```html
<c:set var="myBeanData" scope="request" value="${myBean.myMethod()}"/>
<a id="id" href="${myBeanData}">Link</a>
```